# Cambiar fila por columna y cantidades MYSQLSERVER

Tags: php, mysql, sql

favor de su ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio, tengo la siguiente tabla en MYSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero saber cuantos tipos de muebles hay por año y modelarlos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

atento a sus respuestas y muchas gracias!!

Adjunto query que he intentado para traer las cantidades por año, pero me falta la segunda parte que no logro hacer:

SELECT YEAR(fecha) AS año, tipo_mueble AS muebles, COUNT(tipo_mueble) AS cant_muebles FROM muebles_ingresados GROUP BY YEAR(fecha);

Comment: Por favor edita y muestra que has intentado

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Dónde está el problema? Dices que quieres hacer algo, pero no qué has intentado para conseguirlo. Tal y como está, no es una pregunta, expones lo que quieres para que alguien te lo haga. Intenta dejar un ejemplo de lo que has estado intentando para saber cómo ayudarte :)

Comment: ¡editada estimado!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso que queres hacer se llama tabla pivotante!!! y vos la queres en php o mysql??? porque transformar lo que tenes en la vista es muy distinto a escribir un query que saque eso

Comment: Hola amigo, la quiero en mysql coloque las etiquetas de php y  sql para ver si integrantes de esas etiquetas me ayudan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre hagas una tabla pivote de este modo

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha) AS año,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_mueble = "con broche" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS con_broche,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_mueble = "sin broche" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS sin_broche,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_mueble = "No indicado" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS no_indicado
FROM tabla
GROUP BY año
ORDER BY año ASC;
```

Hacemos un `count` y dentro para cada caso sumamos uno mediante un case para obtener el conteo por cada tipo que deseas se muestre

Solo agregué el uso de `GROUP BY` puesto que estoy usando una función de agregación `COUNT`

Comment: justo lo que andaba buscando pero el resultado me muestra así:

año |con broches | sin broches | no indicado
2017| 2          | 3           | 2

Comment: @francisco_hid dame unos minutos y la corrijo

Comment: ok gracias amigazo!!

Comment: Listo @francisco_hid

Comment: Muchas gracias @alfa p me haz salvado esta vez!!